# Variable sized range for NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: swift, range, swift4, nsmutableattributedstring

I have a label with the string shown below. I would like `secondVariable` to be a different color. I think I understand how to change the color. My problem is getting the range of `secondVariable`.

```
let str = "\(firstVariable) some random text \(secondVariable)"

let secondVariableRange = str.range(???) 
let secondVariableNSRange = NSRange(secondVariableRange, in: str)

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: 
    "\(firstVariable) some random text \(secondVariable)")

attributedString.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.white, 
    range: NSRange(secondVariableNSRange, in: attributedString)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a simpler approach than dealing with ranges. Build up your attributed string in pieces.

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: 
"\(firstVariable) some random text ")
let attrs: [NSAttributedStringKey : Any] = [ .foregroundColor: UIColor.white ]
let secondString = NSAttributedString(string: "\(secondVariable)", attributes: attrs)
attributedString.append(secondString)
```

But if you really want to get the range, use:

```
let secondVariableRange = (str as NSString).range(of: "\(secondVariable)")
```

Comment: I really thought that was going to be a little more complicated. It took me a second to figure out that I also needed to use myLabel.attributedText = ... instead of just myLabel.text = ... Thanks!